# C# WPF Setting data grid column size to auto without knowing the columns

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I have created a function to fill a Data Table from a MySQL Database and then used this function to set the source of a DataGrid which works as expected. My problem is this particular table only has two fields and therefore leaves a lot of space, my research suggests that I have to set the individual column widths to "*" meaning auto, however because the data grid is only filled at compile time I cannot access these columns, or can I?

I am struggling to find a way to edit these columns due to the fact that they are not present until compile time, for example I would also like to change the "Titles" of these columns.

This is my code as it stands;

**Function to Fill Data Table from Query**

```
    // Function to load Query Data into a Data Table
    public DataTable LoadIntoDataTable(string SQLQuery)
    {
        // Create a Data Table 
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        // Check Connection
        if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            try
            {
                // Initialise my data adapter with a query
                MySqlDataAdapter dataSource = new MySqlDataAdapter(SQLQuery, Connection);

                // Fill the Data Table based on the query
                dataSource.Fill(dataTable);

                // Close Connection
                this.CloseConnection();

                // Return Data
                return dataTable;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    default:
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Number, "Error");
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
```

**Function to Fill Data Grid with Information**

```
    public void FillDataGrid()
    {
        // Create a Data Table and fill it with Information from Title Table
        DataTable MyData = myDatabase.LoadIntoDataTable("SELECT * FROM titles");

        // Assign Data Table to the Data Grids Source
        dg_TitlesView.ItemsSource = MyData.DefaultView;

        // Count Table Rows and Change Relevant Label to Reflect this number
        lbl_TitleCount.Content = myDatabase.CountTableRecords("titles");
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hook the [AutoGeneratedColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratedcolumns(v=vs.100).aspx) event, which is fired once all of the auto-generated columns have been created:

```
    dgUsers.AutoGeneratedColumns += dgUsers_AutoGeneratedColumns;
```

and then make your modifications there:

```
    void dgUsers_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var oColumn in dgUsers.Columns)
        {
            // This is how to set the width to *
            oColumn.Width = new DataGridLength(1.0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);

            // The header will contain the column name, so you can change it as needed
            switch (oColumn.Header.ToString().ToLowerInvariant())
            {
                case "id":
                    oColumn.Header = "Identifier";
                    break;

                    // etc.
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update**

To set the alignment on the cell, you need to add a style somewhere in your application (i.e. the window your grid is hosted in):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="CellRightAlign">
        <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalAlignment"
        Value="Right" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

and then set the cell style to use this:

```
            switch (oColumn.Header.ToString().ToLowerInvariant())
            {
                case "id":
                    oColumn.CellStyle = (Style)Resources["CellRightAlign"];
                    oColumn.Header = "Identifier";
                    break;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was really hoping this would work as it looked ideal and avoided XAML. I find keeping most the work in C# adds to reusability. I tried your code - No errors but no change?

Comment: @mbarrot: Sorry about that, copied the wrong code in. I have edited the answer and verified it works correctly now.

Comment: @Blam: I don't think that is a good idea. How will you perform other tasks against the grid columns cells if you don't have a static column name? For example, the headers could easily be updated to a region or customer-specific nomenclature. Changing the names of the columns in the datatable would then require dynamic references to the columns (to map IDs to Header text) through the rest of the code, which makes the implementation unwieldy and fragile.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your answer and am glad to report it working. Do you know any way to center the content whilst your iterating through the columns?

Comment: @mbarrot: you are welcome. I have updated the answer to show how you can apply alignment (you set the CellStyle property of the column). Also, remember that if an answer solves or helps you solve your question, you should click the checkmark next to the answer and the up arrow to let future visitors to the question know that this answer resolved your question.

Answer (score 1):

"*" proportionally divides the space

so 2 columns with "*" for width will take an equal share of available space.

if 1 column has `"*"` and the second `"2*"` then column 1 will have 1/3 and column 2 2/3 of available space.

if you want the columns to auto size then use "auto"

you'll need to bind the columns to the table column names and set the header.

```
<DataGrid Height="104" Width="264">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Column1}" Header="Column1" Width="*" />
          <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Column2}" Header="Column2" Width="*" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I think in DataGridColumns star and auto are the same thing.

Comment: Thankyou @antinutrino this works, however I end up with four columns after this?

Comment: @mbarrot you need to set AutoGenerateColumns="False"

Comment: @Bizz can assure you that auto and * do not have same behaviour in a DataGrid

Comment: @antinutrino Thanks that works. Any idea how to then center the columns?

Comment: @mbarrot you will have to create style for that

<DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
  <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
     <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                 Value="Center" />
  </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>

you can create it as a resource with a key and set the style for the header using StaticResource.

Comment: This works as does @competent_techs answer, both are excellent examples achieving the same result in two different ways. I personally prefer the C# approach. Thankyou for your efforts

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are auto generating the columns so this should work

```
foreach (DataGridColumn dgc in dg1.Columns) dgc.Width = double.NaN;
```

But I think this is more like auto than *

If you know you have two then don't autogenerate and set in XAML as shown in the answer by mbarot.  But I think that will be more like auto also.

Or use a converter and and use 1/2 the width of the DataGrid.  I know I do that ListView GridView.

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid Automatically increase the width of its columns width when its source is changed. But it does 
not decrease them so you should do that manually.

in order to achieve this you can use this event:

```
<DataGrid TargetUpdated="DataGrid_TargetUpdated">
```

And its event handler:

```
private void DataGrid_TargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
    var dg = sender as DataGrid;
    dg.Columns[x].Width = 0;
    dg.UpdateLayout();
    dg.Columns[x].Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
}
```